# iOS Resolve SRV Record without Domain

Tags: ios, objective-c, dns

I am trying to resolve a SRV Record with my iOS App.
I have come so far that I indeed can resolve the DNS record.
This works only if the SRV Record Contains a valid Domain Ending.

Each Customer has its on domain so I can't hard Code the Domain.
Furthermore I don't want the User to specify a Domain Name. This would make the SRV record useless.

I hope Somebody can explain to me how the resolve an DNS Record without the Domain. Or Resolve the Domain first an the do the SRV query. Thanks a lot.

This Works: _sip._tls.mydomain.com

This Should be the Goal: _sip._tls

And please do not give me a suggestion for how to resolve _sip._tls
this is only a placeholder. My real SRV record is a custom record like "_myApplication._tcp" THX

```
- (void)updateDnsRecords
{
    NSLog(@"DNS update");
    DNSServiceRef       sdRef;
    DNSServiceErrorType err;

    NSTimeInterval remainingTime = 3.0;
    NSDate*        startTime = [NSDate date];

    err = DNSServiceQueryRecord(&sdRef, 0, 0,
                                "_sip._tls.mydomain.com",
                                kDNSServiceType_SRV,
                                kDNSServiceClass_IN,
                                processDnsReply,
                                &remainingTime);

    // This is necessary so we don't hang forever if there are no results
    int            dns_sd_fd = DNSServiceRefSockFD(sdRef);
    int            nfds      = dns_sd_fd + 1;
    fd_set         readfds;
    int            result;

    while (remainingTime > 0)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(dns_sd_fd, &readfds);

        struct timeval tv;
        tv.tv_sec  = (time_t)remainingTime;
        tv.tv_usec = (remainingTime - tv.tv_sec) * 1000000;

        result = select(nfds, &readfds, (fd_set*)NULL, (fd_set*)NULL, &tv);
        if (result == 1)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(dns_sd_fd, &readfds))
            {
                err = DNSServiceProcessResult(sdRef);
                if (err != kDNSServiceErr_NoError)
                {
                    NSLog(@"There was an error reading the DNS SRV records.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (result == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"DNS SRV select() timed out");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (errno == EINTR)
            {
                NSLog(@"DNS SRV select() interrupted, retry.");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"DNS SRV select() returned %d errno %d %s.", result, errno, strerror(errno));
                break;
            }
        }

        NSTimeInterval elapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
        remainingTime -= elapsed;
    }

    DNSServiceRefDeallocate(sdRef);
   }
  static void processDnsReply(DNSServiceRef       sdRef,
                        DNSServiceFlags     flags,
                        uint32_t            interfaceIndex,
                        DNSServiceErrorType errorCode,
                        const char*         fullname,
                        uint16_t            rrtype,
                        uint16_t            rrclass,
                        uint16_t            rdlen,
                        const void*         rdata,
                        uint32_t            ttl,
                        void*               context
                        )
{

 NSTimeInterval* remainingTime = (NSTimeInterval*)context;

//  If a timeout occurs the value of the errorCode argument will be
//  kDNSServiceErr_Timeout.
if (errorCode != kDNSServiceErr_NoError)
{
    return;
}

//  The flags argument will have the kDNSServiceFlagsAdd bit set if the
//  callback is being invoked when a record is received in response to
//  the query.
//
//  If kDNSServiceFlagsAdd bit is clear then callback is being invoked
//  because the record has expired, in which case the ttl argument will
//  be 0.
if ((flags & kDNSServiceFlagsMoreComing) == 0)
{
    *remainingTime = 0;
}

// Record parsing code below was copied from Apple SRVResolver sample.
NSMutableData *         rrData = [NSMutableData data];
dns_resource_record_t * rr;
uint8_t                 u8;
uint16_t                u16;
uint32_t                u32;


u8 = 0;
[rrData appendBytes:&u8 length:sizeof(u8)];
u16 = htons(kDNSServiceType_SRV);
[rrData appendBytes:&u16 length:sizeof(u16)];
u16 = htons(kDNSServiceClass_IN);
[rrData appendBytes:&u16 length:sizeof(u16)];
u32 = htonl(666);
[rrData appendBytes:&u32 length:sizeof(u32)];
u16 = htons(rdlen);
[rrData appendBytes:&u16 length:sizeof(u16)];
[rrData appendBytes:rdata length:rdlen];

rr = dns_parse_resource_record([rrData bytes], (uint32_t) [rrData length]);

// If the parse is successful, add the results.
if (rr != NULL)
{
    NSString *target;

    target = [NSString stringWithCString:rr->data.SRV->target encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if (target != nil)
    {
        uint16_t priority = rr->data.SRV->priority;
        uint16_t weight   = rr->data.SRV->weight;
        uint16_t port     = rr->data.SRV->port;
        char *adresse     = rr->data.SRV->target;

        NSLog(@"Prio:%hu",priority);
        NSLog(@"weight:%hu",weight);
        NSLog(@"port:%hu",port);
        NSLog(@"adresse:%s",adresse);
        NSLog(@"fullname:%s",fullname);

        //[[FailoverWebInterface sharedInterface] addDnsServer:target priority:priority weight:weight port:port ttl:ttl];  // You'll have to do this in with your own method.
    }
}

dns_free_resource_record(rr);
}
```

Comment: You need to determine the default domain suffix for the current network. `DNSServiceEnumerateDomains` may help https://developer.apple.com/reference/dnssd/1804754-dnsserviceenumeratedomains?language=objc

Comment: Hey Paulw11 any code example you can provide? The class looks like the one I was looking for. Will do a google search myself. Would be great if you know how to use it. (Code example)